# How do you create a 3rd column which is the sum of the first two column when querying a table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have queried a table and have produced a table with two columns both containing integers, how would I produce a third column which is a sum of the first two columns in the one query?

Answer (score 3):

You can use arithmetic operators in your query:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, column_a + column_b AS a_plus_b
FROM   my_table
```